# Python function to remove some content from string item in a list of strings

Tags: python

String in the input list is formatted as 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'.
The function should return a list of strings where each element in the returned list contains only the date in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format e.g

```
lst = ['2019-11-29 12:50:54', '2019-11-28 12:46:53', '2019-11-27 12:46:10']
```

expected result ['2019-11-29', 2019-11-28, 2019-11-27']

Comment: Can you not just slice the first 10 chars? eg `result = [el[:10] for e in lst]` ?

Comment: `[k.split()[0] for k in lst]` would work as well, but not that good

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through the list you can slice the first n characters in the string using the following - change 11 to the desired length depending on your needs

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = lst[i][:11]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using datetime and specifying desired date formats, you can do something like

```
new_list = [datetime.strptime(item, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for item in lst ]
```

Comment: Thanks , this work too, though I wanted to avoid using datetime at first